# Plot results from the model returned by lm

Tags: r, plot, curve-fitting, lm

Sorry if this is trivial, have not found a solution.

To keep this simple, I have 5 points (say, `d0 = c(1,2,3,4,5)`) and 5 values (say `f0 = c(0.8950514, 1.240066, 1.410252, 1.494778, 1.514794)`).

I want to generalize this and find a function `f` such that `f(d0) = f0`. Pretty simple. For this, if I got it right, I need to do some trial and error to find the right structure for `f`; then I can extract its parameters with `lm`. Right?

So, I start trying a simple linear model:

```
model <- lm(f0 ~ d0)$coefficients
```

Then I want to plot it to see the actual fit:

```
lines(d0, model[[1]] + d0*model[[2]])
```

### Issue

Things get boring when trying other kinds of dependencies. For example, I can guess a log log dependency between the two:

```
model <- lm(log(f0) ~ log(d0))$coefficients
```

But then to plot the real function I need to alter the call to lines to

```
lines(d0, exp(model2[[1]] + model2[[2]]*log(d0)))
```

Now if I were to try another kind of formula, I would have to use a different line of code for `lines`.

### Questions

1. Is there a way to automatically plot the results of `lm` (in the form of `lines(d0, predicted.f)`), perhaps using the information in `lm$call`?

My wish is something like:

```
model <- lm(f0 ~ d0)
plotFromModel(d0, model)
model <- lm(log(f0) ~ log(d0))
plotFromModel(d0, model)
```

2. Is there something I am missing here? Should this simple task be done with `lm` and different formulas or is there a more obvious path?

### Edit

Looks like there's no more obvious path. I clarify here that this question comes out of necessity to find the best-fit 1d curve for these 5 points. So, while we are forced to use `lm`, one has to be open to all kinds of formulas, like

```
f0 ~ d0

log(f0) ~ d0

f0 ~ d0 + I(log(d0)^2)
```

And so on. On top of that, I am still looking for a one dimensional function, i.e. an `y = f(x)` where both x and y are scalars and there's no other parameter involved.

Other typical requirements in a curve-fitting problem would be that, once you have found the model from the 5 points, you can see its real curve (-> use d's of arbitrary lengths), and you can compare it with other models you are testing. I'd like to replicate the following behavior:

```
d0 <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
f0 <- c(0.8950514, 1.240066, 1.410252, 1.494778, 1.514794)
d <- seq(from = 1, to = 5, length.out = 200)

windows(w=700,h=500)
plot(d0, f0, type='b',col='black', log='xy',lwd=4)
grid()

m <- lm(f0 ~ d0)$coefficients
lines(d, m[1] + m[2]*d, col='orange', lwd=3)

m <- lm(log(f0) ~ log(d0))$coefficients
lines(d, exp(m[1] + m[2]*log(d)), col='blue', lwd=3)

m <- lm(log(f0) ~ log(log(d0)))$coefficients
lines(d, exp(m[1] + m[2]*log(log(d))), col='green', lwd=3)

m <- lm(log(f0) ~ log(d0) + I(log(d0)^2))$coefficients
lines(d, exp(m[1] + m[2]*log(d) + m[3]*log(d)^2), col='red', lwd=3)

m <- lm(f0 ~ d0 + I(d0^2))$coefficients
lines(d, m[1] + m[2]*d + m[3]*d^2, col='pink', lwd=3)
```

[image]
*From this I can tell that red is better.*

From the great answer below this turned out to be non-trivial so personally I'll just stick with the manual approach. This should be possible, since the formula is kept in `model$call`, but I can live without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plotFromModel` assumes a model with a possibly transformed `y` value and a single `x` value; however, the `x` value can be involved in multiple `lm` terms and each may transform `x`.  `finv` must specify the inverse transformation of the LHS (or can be omitted if `y` is not transformed).  If `add` is FALSE (the default) it plots `y` vs `x` and then the fit. If `add` is TRUE it only plots the fit overplotting any existing plot. ... are passed to the `lines` command that plots the fit.   Note that it refits the model.

*Also, note that the different fits are not comparable using conventional linear regression tests since they are using the sums of the squares of different funcdtions of `y`.*

```
plotFromModel <- function(x, fm, finv = identity, add = FALSE, ...) {

   # DF's columns are y and x
   DF <- cbind(finv(fm$model[1]), x)
   names(DF) <- all.vars(terms(fm))

   if (!add) plot(DF[2:1]) # plot y vs. x
   fm.new <- lm(terms(fm), DF) # refit using new x
   lines(finv(fitted(fm.new)) ~ x, ...)
}

d0 = c(1,2,3,4,5) 
f0 = c(0.8950514, 1.240066, 1.410252, 1.494778, 1.514794)

fm0 <- lm(f0 ~ d0)  
fm1 <- lm(log(f0) ~ log(d0))
fm2 <- lm(log(f0) ~ log(d0) + I(log(d0)^2))
fm3 <- lm(f0 ~ d0 + I(d0^2))

plotFromModel(d0, fm0, col = 1)
plotFromModel(d0, fm1, exp, add = TRUE, col = 2, lty = 2)
plotFromModel(d0, fm2, exp, add = TRUE, col = 3, lty = 3)
plotFromModel(d0, fm3, add = TRUE, col = 4, lty = 4)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I wanted to pass d0 because I might want to evaluate the predicted f on a different set of d's. I'll check this soon, thank you!

Comment: Also, what if `model <- lm(f0 ~ d0 + I(d0^2))`? looks like abline will use only the first two coefficients.

Comment: Hey, you did some great work. I still have troubles which I'm trying to figure out. First is that it doesn't allow d's of arbitrary length, while I would like to see the curve for the model I just found. Second is that, when using `log(f0) ~ something`, plotFromModel actually plots log(f0), while I would like it to plot f0. That makes impossible, for instance, to compare different models using a linesFromModel function. Going to edit my question to reflect that, but anyway, you did great work and I think this will be useful in the future.

Comment: Have revised to correspond to revised question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use predict to apply the model to your data. Here is an example:

```
d0 = c(1,2,3,4,5)
f0 = c(0.8950514, 1.240066, 1.410252, 1.494778, 1.514794)
model <- lm(f0 ~ d0)

plot(d0, f0)
lines(d0, predict(model, data.frame(d0 = d0)))
```

Maybe there is some more elegant way than creating a data frame as an argument for predict but it should be at least a sufficient solution.

Comment: Yeah, I am trying it right now but I can't make it work.

Comment: You're right that is not that simple for log model. I'll try to find something more general.

Comment: @mvai I was actually asking Ardavel ;-) it cannot work without a transformation like the one you had to do